# Greater than or equal to isn't working with floats

Tags: python, variables, math

When I have a number that has a decimal in it I set it to a float but that seems to stop the greater than and less then from working

```
nm=".01"

nm=int(float(nm))
if nm >= .01:
  print("True")
else:
  print("False")
```

When the script finishes it prints False when it should be True because .01 is equal to .01

I've tried stuff like switching which order the code is in, rearranging the code, and even getting rid of the float but nothing is working.

I am really new to coding so please bare with me.

Comment: What makes you think this isn't "working"?

Comment: What do you think `int` does with a number less than 1?

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. There is a separate answer section.

Answer (score 4):

```
nm=int(float(nm))
```

lets say the input is `"0.1"` as input() returns string

it first gets converted to `0.1` by float()

then it gets converted to `0` by int()

and `0` happens to be less than `.00000000001`